# How to determine by reflection if a Method returns 'void'

Tags: java, reflection, methods

I have a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object and I would like to know if it's return type is `void`.

I've checked the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and there is a `getReturnType()` method that returns a Class object. The thing is that they don't say what would be the return type if the method is void.

Thanks!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
if( method.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)){
    out.println("It does");
 }
```

Quick sample:

```
$cat X.java  

import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class X {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        for( Method m : X.class.getMethods() ) {
            if( m.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)){
                System.out.println( m.getName()  + " returns void ");
            }
        }
    }

    public void hello(){}
}
$java X
hello returns void 
main returns void 
wait returns void 
wait returns void 
wait returns void 
notify returns void 
notifyAll returns void
```

Comment: For some reason with java 6 I had to replace `Void.TYPE` with `Void.class` otherwise the check would always fail. Ideas why?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta Void.TYPE is the same as void.class and represents the primitive type void. Void.class represents the reference type Void. So maybe your method returns Void instead of void.

Answer (score 36):

```
method.getReturnType()==void.class     √

method.getReturnType()==Void.Type      √

method.getReturnType()==Void.class     X
```

Comment: I wish more people on SO responded with such minimal and informative answers.

Answer (score 11):

`method.getReturnType()` returns `void.class`/`Void.TYPE`.

Answer (score 8):

It returns `java.lang.Void.TYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another, perhaps less conventional way:

`public boolean doesReturnVoid(Method method) {
    if (void.class.equals(method.getReturnType())) 
        return true;
}`