# what is the difference between Void and unbounded wildcard in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between an object of a Void type and that of an unbounded wildcard type in Java generics?  I mean I understand the use of <?>, and also the use of Void in terms of reflection, but I was a bit intrigued when I saw the Java source code for

```
java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService
```

and its method

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    ...
    RunnableFuture<Void> ftask = new TaskFor(task, null);
    ...
    return ftask;
```

where inside the method it uses a RunnableFuture<Void> instead of RunnableFuture<?>

can someone help me understand the reason behind this?  Thanks

Comment: The difference is that there is nothing the same about them. Not a real question.

Comment: that's why I said I was confused.  Could you please elaborate a little more?  Just saying nothing the same doesn't really help.

Comment: @Jim I don't know why the comment I posted below is marked as deleted, but do you seriously see a Void keyword in the submit function of AbstractExecutorService? Because it's not there at least in JDK 6 source code.

Comment: @Arham I am pretty sure your comment is still there.  Just found out that they changed this from JDK6 to JDK7 (which was what I was looking at -- see rolve's reply below)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Void](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) is a special class that is used to represent **no** return value. While there is nothing special about `Void` *per se*, it can't be (and never is) instantiated, so the only possible value for it is always `null`. It is used for two things:

1. To say that a generic method or class has no return value.
2. To represent the `void` return type in Java reflection using `Void.TYPE`. See [How to determine by reflection if a Method returns 'void'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1924253/1374678) for example.

So it is very different from a wildcard, which is no actual class but represents one specific, *unknown* type at compile time. At runtime, it is [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) like every other generic type.

---

Regarding the `submit` method. Here are the two implementations from JDK 6:

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Object> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

and JDK 7:

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Void> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

As you can see, the type was changed to `Void` only in JDK 7, probably because it makes more sense conceptually. But since the interface of the method could not be changed (for compatibility reasons and because the method implements `Future<?> submit(Runnable task)` of the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface), the return type `Future<?>` stayed the same. That's my explanation.

Comment: Thank you and yes, but I am still not quite sure why the submit() method returns a Future<?> instead of a Future<Void>

Comment: Thank you rolve, especially for posting JDK6 and JDK7 side by side, which made things more clear. So it seems more like a matter of what makes more sense rather than what's right and wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Void isn't a wildcard, it represents that there is no value to return at all.

The [Void javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)...

Comment: Thank you. I understand the Void as what its javadoc says, but why doesn't the submit() method return a Future<Void>; instead of Future<?> ?

Answer (score 3):

[Void](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) is the object representation of void.  Where void returns nothing from a method, Void ALWAYS returns null.  This is because void isn't an object and therefore cannot be used with Generics.  It's nice to use Void with Futures when you don't need any return values.

Comment: Did you take a look at the source code? For returning void you just need a Runnable Interface and it's run method and not a Future with void.